# ko.mapping create function works on the top level array of 'Children' only in hierarchical viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, mapping

I'm trying to add a computed observable to a hierarchical viewmodel using ko.mapping plugin create function. But the function works on the top level 'children' array only! 
Code is as following:

```
Children:[{
    Name: "Page 1",
    Children: [ {
        Name: "Page 1 > 1",
        Children: [{
        Name: "Page 1 > 1 > 1",
        Children: []
    }
,{
        Name: "Page 1 > 1 > 2",
        Children: []
    }
]
    }
    ]
},
{
    Name: "Page 2",
    Children: [
    {
        Name: "Page 16",
        Children: []
    }
    ]
},
{
    Name: "Page 3",
    Children: [
    {
        Name: "aaaaa",
        Children: []
    }
]
```

My functions are as following

```
     var computed = function (data) {
                                var self = this;
                                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
                                self.Uri = ko.computed(function () {
                                    console.log(self.Name());
                                    return self.Name() + " Something";
                                });
                            };

     var mapping = {
                    'Children': {
                        create: function (o) {
                            return new computed(o.data);

                        }
                    }
                };

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, vm);
```

Is there a way to make the 'computed' function run on all 'children' arrays?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide mapping options for children too. Try to update `computed` function as follow:

```
 var computed = function (data) {
                            var self = this;
                            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
                            self.Uri = ko.computed(function () {
                                console.log(self.Name());
                                return self.Name() + " Something";
                            });
                        };
```

Comment: Artem. Your function is just a copy and paste of mine :)

Comment: No, Here is the difference - ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);